# Como ter acesso ao css do bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Estou utilizando uma barra de navegação do bootstrap e gostaria de aumentar o espaço entre os botões e mudar suas cores, editando attravés de um arquivo externo, mas não sei onde consigo o código css dele (é minha primeira vez utilizando o bootstrap)...
 o HTML está assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">titulo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">

          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my- sm-0" type="submit">BOTAOA</button>

          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">BOTAOB</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Geralmente fica dentro da pasta do bootstrap, mas precisamente na pasta css e no arquivo bootstrap.min.css ou bootstrap.css. Depende de qual dos dois arquivos vc está chamando.

Comment: é que eu não baixei nada pra usar, eu só utilizei o link de referencia... vou tentar baixar os arquivos e ver se funciona

Comment: Mas eu não entendi direito. Todas essas mudanças que vc citou, tu pode fazer utilizando classes do bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É mais fácil você "criar" sua própria classe do que alterar a classe do Bootstrap, e se você já tem conhecimento pra alterar, você consegue criar a sua. Pra você alterar, você precisaria ter os arquivos baixados dentro da pasta do seu projeto, o que deixaria ele mais lento, é melhor deixar por cdn mesmo.

Pra criar sua classe, basta você criar um arquivos css (eu normalmente chamo de custom.css), procura a classe que você desejaria alterar dentro do arquivo bootstrap.css (é mais difícil de achar no arquivo bootstrap.min.css), copia ela inteira, joga na custom.css e faça as alterações, muda de nome, cores, padding, assim como fiz aqui.

[image: meu código]

Aí no caso eu peguei o btn-primary que é azul, e criei um btn-caixa que é laranja. Valeu, espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida comenta aqui

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma

```
<div class="unique-section-name"></div>
```

em volta do código que você deseja alterar as propriedades do css presente no bootstrap.

```
.unique-section-name .bootstrap-class { css here }
```

Assim você altera as propriedades do css do bootstrap em um trexo do seu sistema(unique-section-name) sem alterar em outros.

EDIT1: Para saber qual classe você deve alterar, na teoria, você deveria consultar a documentação oficial do bootstrap, mas, provavelmente será mais fácil pelo inspect do seu browser.

Obs: O bootstrap era útil, assim como o jQuery, em momentos da humanidade nos quais grande parte de nós ainda nem éramos vivos. Caso esteja aprendendo e não dando manutenção para um sistema mais antigo, não utilize nenhum deles, atualmente as versões de CSS e JS te dão ferramentas para lidar com páginas web de formas extremamente efetivas.

Obs2: esse padrão de isolar uma classe em uma 'seção' do seu sistema utilizando uma classe única para essa seção, é a base do css local(componente isolado) em frameworks como angular, Vue e bibliotecas como React.